# C++. Nested loop box shape increment

Tags: c++, loops, nested, shapes, box

Im currently having a hardtime to incrementing a box shape. So here's the picture:

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpKjH.png)

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int box(int);

int main() {
    int input;
    cout << "Enter input: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << endl;
    box(input);

    return 0;
}

int box(int input) {
    if (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3) {
       switch(input) {
            case 1:
                for (int a=1; a<=3; a++) {
                    cout << "*";
                }
                cout << endl;

                for (int b=1; b<=1; b++) {
                    for (int c=1; c<=1; c++) {
                        cout << "*";
                }
                for(int d=1; d<=1; d++) {
                        cout << " ";
                }
                cout << "*" << endl;
            }

            for (int e=1; e<=3; e++) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            break;
    }
}
else {
    cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
}

return input;
```

}

I'am new at programming C++. Im trying to get the logic and code here. But its so hard for me to do it. Im trying to input 1 and the box will appear. I want to recreate the code with one function whose input will increment the box.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially *links* to images of text (links can go away without warning, making your question useless). Instead you should copy and paste the actual text into the question body. You might want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You started solving it too specifically: starting with one box. Try to see what they all have in common. Taking `N` as the input,

- The output has 3, 5, 7 lines: `2 * N + 1`
- The first line is special; it has an `"*"`, then `N` times `" * *"`
- The other lines come in `N` pairs
- The first line in a pair, the mostly empty one, has `"*"`, and then `N` times `"    "` (4 spaces) or `"   *"` (3 spaces and a star). For `I`-th line-pair, there is `I` of the former ones, and `N - I` of the latter ones, with `I` going from 0 to `N - 1`.
- The second line in a pair, the one with the box bottom, similarly has `"*"`, and then either `"    "` (4 spaces) or `" * *"`, with `I + 1` of the former ones, and `N - (I + 1)` of the latter ones.

Now you can draw even 4, or 5 boxes - they all follow the same rules.